# Date-axis for d3.js

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I'm playing again with d3.js the javascript library. I am able to create a chart with 2 numeric axes but now I want to have one numeric axis and one axis with a date. Unfortunately I'm not able to do this.

First of all, thats the code that is not running:

```
d3.json('builds.json', 
        function(data){

            var format = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d");

            data.forEach(function(d) {
                d.finished_at = format.parse(d.finished_at);
              });

            var margin = {top: 40, right: 40, bottom: 40, left: 40},
            width = 960,
            height = 500;

            var x = d3.time.scale()
                .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.finished_at; }))
               .range([0, width - margin.right - margin.left]);

            var y = d3.scale.linear()
                .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.result; }))
                .range([height - margin.top - margin.bottom, 0]);

            var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(x)
                .orient("bottom");

            var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(y)
                .orient("left");

            var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                .attr("width", width)
                .attr("height", height)
              .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

            svg.selectAll("circle")
                .data(data)
              .enter().append("circle")
                .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.finished_at); })
                .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.result); })
                .attr("r", 6);

            svg.append("g") // Render the axis by calling a <g> selection.
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + y.range()[0] + ")") //setzt x-achse an null punkt von y-achse
                .call(xAxis);

            svg.append("g")
                .call(yAxis);

        });
```

The variable finished_at looks like this: "finished_at":"2011-11-20" and I tried to parse it.

But the output is the following:

[image]

Can anybody please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem likely lies with your data. You will need to confirm that all of the `finished_at` values in your JSON are in the correct format.

Your code appears to work perfectly well with a small working JSON dataset: http://bl.ocks.org/4162693